# laravel catch all route as last option

Tags: php, laravel

I am not sure the best way to do this but basically I have some routes set up and some vendor ones as well but my kind of "catch all" route is getting called when I need the vendor "/forum" to be used.

Here are my routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); });
Route::get('/contact', function () { return view('contact'); });
Route::get('/login', function () { return view('login'); });
Route::get('/signup', 'UserController@create');
Route::get('/logout', 'UserController@logout');
Route::get('/{slug}', 'PageController@show');
```

You can see the last route basically just gets the slug and and then in the controller I return the page by slug. The issue is with /forum the `PageController@show` is getting called since I assume Laravel looks at this route file before the vendor. Is there a better way of setting it up so `Route::get('/{slug}', 'PageController@show');` gets called as the last possible option after vendor routes as well?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel routes are loaded in order they are defined so the only way to have your `/forum` match before `/{slug}` is to make sure that route is loaded first.  To guarantee it is loaded last I would suggest adding it after all the other routes are loaded in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` which would look like:

```
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();
    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    Route::get('/{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PageController@show');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Even when I put it in the `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` forum tries to use that wrong controller.  `/forum` route is handled by a vendor package so I need to load `Route::get('/{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PageController@show');
}` after vendor routes as well

Comment: ohhh, then put that vendor's service provider in the `providers` array in `config/app.php` before `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,` and it should load that route first before your routes.